# Call PHP function on button click considering the sequence of list item

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, ajax

Hey guys I need your help with a little project. I avoided using AJAX because I just dont have the time to learn it properly but I think I need one AJAX function.
My problem is that I want to call a PHP function that writes into my database. I want to write the text of my list items and their position into my database on button click. I am using JqueryUI to make my list items dragable. The Code looks like this:

```
<ul id="sortable">
         <li class="ui-state-default">item1</li>
         <li class="ui-state-default">item2</li>
         <li class="ui-state-default">item4</li>
         <li class="ui-state-default">item3</li>
         <li class="ui-state-default">item5</li>
</ul>
```

The result should be something like this:

```
Position Text
1        item1
2        item2
3        item4
4        item3
5        item5
```

Maybe I could solve this with auto-increment to skip the writing of my position?

Comment: you definitely need ajax, no escape.

Comment: And show us what have you tried? and `js` and `php`?!

Answer (score 0):

You need AJAX to do this.  Fortunately, the sortable has a decept API that will allow for you to get the updated positions and post them to the server fairly easily.

- Through the API provided by Sortable, you should define an update method on the sortable object, see http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update
- To make it easier on yourself, give elements in your list data-ids and data-orders when rendering them on the frontend.

Here is a brief example, given that models is an array of your list elements, and each object in the models array has a corresponding database row id, and a current order position.

```
<ul id="sortable">
<?php foreach ($models as $item: ?>
    <li data-id="<?php echo $item->id; ?>"><?php echo $item->name; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Then when creating the sortable object, you'll define an update method that should be used.

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
  update: function (event, ui) {
    var newOrder = $("#sortable").sortable("toArray", {"attribute: "data-id"});
    $.post('route/for/updating/order', {
       'order': newOrder
    });
  }
});
```

When a change is made, a POST request will be sent to the route `route/for/updating/order` with the post parameter, 'order' and the newOrder object.  By default the `toArray` method would use the 'id' attribute, but we tell it to use the database row value for easier server side processing.

You can see more about the toArray API feature here http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray